# Brew service getting error in httpd as Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, macos-ventura, launchctl

When I try to `brew services start httpd`  to start, I am getting the below error:

```
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/admin/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 5
```

The Mac Version is 13.4.1. I uninstalled httpd and installed it again, but it's still going to the same error.

After restarting the services and  the system multiple times, there is still no hope.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This I/O error is ambiguous, and can be caused by a number of issues. Elsewhere you will see suggestions to check the ownership of apache log files (in case the process is having trouble writing to the error log.)
I have also seen this issue when the HomeBrew Shared Object file is not signed. Ventura requires that all *.so files be code signed. You will need to set up code signing locally to do that. Then the command would be:

> codesign --sign "YourName" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

This allows the libphp.so file to run.